# Power Apps Save Screen PDF to SharePoint List New Record

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, attachments, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have an app with two screens.

- Screen #1 pulls fields from a SharePoint List for the user to fill out the form
- Screen #2 asks additional details that are not stored in SharePoint but instead are part of an email request.

I am wondering if anyone has any advice on how to possibly save an output from the PDF function of Screen #2 (that I attach to the email) to the specific SharePoint List attachment field from Screen #1.

I would think it is possible but the record hasn't been created yet so I am not sure that it is.

Comment: do you mean saving the email attachment (PDF) as an SP List Attachment?

Comment: @codeandfootball yes to the item that it is creating on screen 1 (being submitted all at once with screen #2)